# TextField stops after writing 1 letter flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, textfield

I am trying to modify a `TextField` inside an `ExpansionTile title` and when I modify the text I want to update data in my database firestore, this part works fine. The problem is when I write something in my `TextField` I can only write one letter and then I have to select the TextField again.[Initial text field value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EeZqQ.png)
[Second text field value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yABvG.png)

In the second picture after writing the number 2 in test the 'blue mark' exits the TextField and if I want to write in the TextField again I have to select the text field again.
This is the TextField code inside the expansion tile, all this code is inside a stream where each list tile is an entry from the database:

```
return SizedBox(

        width: double.infinity,
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Column(
                children: [
                  ListView.builder(
                    physics: const ClampingScrollPhysics(),
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    itemCount: widget.shoppingListsCart.length,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {

                      String shoppingCartListName =
                          widget.shoppingListsCart.elementAt(index).name;
                      final shoppingListId =
                          widget.shoppingListsCart.elementAt(index).shoppingListId;
                      TextEditingController _textEditingControllerShoppingListName = TextEditingController();
                      _textEditingControllerShoppingListName.text = shoppingCartListName;


                      _textEditingControllerShoppingListName.addListener(() {
                          widget.firebaseCloudStorage.updateShoppingListName(
                          widget.shoppingCartListId, shoppingListId, _textEditingControllerShoppingListName.text);
                       });
                      return Column(
                        children: [

                          ExpansionTile(
                              backgroundColor: Colors.indigo,
                              title: SizedBox(
                                child: Row(
                                    children: [
                                      SizedBox(
                                        width: 220,
                                        child: TextField(
                                          decoration: const InputDecoration(
                                            border: InputBorder.none,
                                            counterText: '',
                                          ),
                                          controller: _textEditingControllerShoppingListName,
                                          maxLength: 35,),
                                      ), ),
                                      Row(
                                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                        children:  [
                                          IconButton(onPressed: (){
                                           
                                          }, icon:Icon(Icons.edit,)),
                                          IconButton(onPressed: () {}, icon: Icon(Icons.delete)),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    ]),
                              ),

                              children: [
                                ProductsInShoppingListView(
                                  shoppingListName: shoppingCartListName,
                                  shoppingCartId: widget.shoppingCartListId,
                                  shoppingListId: shoppingListId,
                                  firebaseCloudStorage: widget.firebaseCloudStorage,
                                ),
                              ]),
                        ],
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                  Column(
                    children: [
                      ProductsInCartView(
                          shoppingCartId: state.shoppingCartId),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),],
          ),
        ),
      );
```

I tried using a Future in the text field and changing from a stateless widget to a stateful widget, the error is something like this [TextField accepts only one letter and loses focus after each letter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70048149/textfield-accepts-only-one-letter-and-loses-focus-after-each-letter) but since I am using flutter that solution didn't work for me. I don't know what is the error because the console doesn't say anything. Please help, thank you.

Comment: Can you add the full widget code?

Comment: I updated the code. I call this class from a Stream, so I think that maybe the error is that I update the data, and then I get the data instant again from the database with the stream, maybe that is why it don't let me write more characters. But not sure if this is the error and how to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

did you try it? It's TextFormField. Here I fixed the value 1, we can make it a dynamic value. But I hope this will be helpful to think about next.

```
    TextFormField(
      onChanged: (value) {
        if (value.length == 1) {
          FocusScope.of(context).nextFocus(); //whatever you want to do
        }
      },
      inputFormatters: [
        LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(1)
      ],
    ),
```

Comment: Still didnt work, but I din't know about the FocusScope class, gonna check it because now I think the error is that I am losing the FocusScope when value change. Thank you